How does Biden staying in the presidential race hurt Democrats in Congress?
I was reading an article on Yahoo about people trying to convince Biden to exit the race.
There was a quote in the article where some Democratic leaders came to Biden with information

indicating that he risked taking down control of Congress with him if
he stayed on the same path.

https://www.yahoo.com/news/were-close-end-biden-world-191219107.html
The article doesn't tell me how this is true so I'm wondering how is this true politically?  My initial thoughts are the Democratic leaders just grasping at any reason to force him out just because of his debate performance and this was one of the reasons they could come up with.
Can anyone explain what the political reasoning would be that a voter who doesn't like Biden's debate performance would also not vote for any Democrats period?

I guess this Q could use a bit more context https://edition.cnn.com/2024/07/17/politics/nancy-pelosi-biden-conversation/index.html

I think they use the polls to show how bad they would fair in an election if it were held now. Of course polls were never reliable. They were panicking and started attacking Biden left and right.

Lots of American voters think in party block terms. In other words if a given voter decides not to vote for a Democrat President then he is likely not going to vote Democrat in other ways. Part of this is just because they view the President as the leader of the party and the party as a monolithic block. But also if a person decides not to vote for a President ("I'm a Democrat but I can't bring myself to vote for Biden") then they are probably not going to turn out to vote at all. Especially since voting in the US is actually pretty difficult and involves lots of waiting in line. That reduces Democrat support for other legislators.
US ballots also often have dozens of electoral races to vote on, and in order to reduce the ridiculous complexity of this most ballots have an option to vote for a "slate", where you can make a simple action to vote for every Democrat (or Republican) on the ballot. Lots of voters are going to take that option and change their entire vote rather than vote for a President from one party, a Senator from another and a whole variety of judges, police chiefs, attorneys general and dog catchers.

Voting is only difficult in some places. Some states make it very easy. Suggest you edit

I’ve never heard of a slate option but I’ll take your word for it

I remember seeing the slate option in mechanical voting booths when I was growing up in NY. But I've never seen it on the ballots we use now in MA, where you fill in ovals with a pen.

@AzorAhai-him- It existed at least historically with mechanical voting booths in some parts of Ohio, but seems to be gone with the digital ones that are mostly in use here now. That doesn’t change the fact that a nontrivial percentage of Americans effectively vote that way though.

I scorlled through sample ballots on Ballotpedia and saw slates only IN, KY, MI and SC, which is far from most ballots. Maybe DJ should edit that too.

With electronic voting machines, the "slate" option only sets the default for each race, but each race can then be changed by the user right up until they lock in their vote. (Or, in some cases, the race might not have a candidate from the selected party, so no option is selected until they do so manually.) As such, it might be an option on the machine even if it's not shown on the ballot.

I've never had to wait in line for any significant amount of time to vote in decades of voting. People who aren't from the US (and some people who are) really need to learn that each state and territory of the US has its own voting system (also laws.)

@GalacticCowboy In New York, you fill out a scantron-type sheet which is electronically counted.  There's no circle for party and often the same candidate shows up multiple times on the ballot under different parties. IIRC, there have been times when there was only one candidate, but they were listed five times under different parties. Voting is a state-level concern.

"probably not going to turn out to vote at all" this is really the only correct part of this answer which would make a good answer if it didn't contain all the other incorrect assertions.

Regarding the whole discussion about the slate, it's worth noting that political parties often campaign as a slate; which is the important part of the answer; if people may not want to vote for Biden because of something specific to him, the voter often associates that particular thing with the rest of the slate that he runs with, even if they had nothing to do with that thing. Unless he stepped down from the race, he was effectively saying that his things were stuff the Democrats down the ballot were also on board with.

I guess this Q could use a bit more context

Former House Speaker Nancy Pelosi privately told President Joe Biden in a recent conversation that polling shows that the president cannot defeat Donald Trump and that Biden could destroy Democrats’ chances of winning the House in November if he continues seeking a second term, according to four sources briefed on the call.

Emphasis mine. While the piece does not exactly elaborate on how [Pelosi or anyone else envisages] the latter could happen, I suppose the general theory is some kind of negative coattail effect:

Presidential coattails is the ability of a presidential candidate to bring out supporters who then vote for his party's candidates for other offices. In effect, the other candidates are said to ride on the presidential candidate's coattails.
[...]
There is also the "negative coattail" effect in which a controversial presidential candidate may hurt candidates on the party's ticket running for lower offices. Goldwater's poor showing in the presidential election of 1964 led to the defeat of dozens of Republicans in the House of Representatives, leaving Johnson a large Democratic majority to pass his agenda.

Generally, it's much easier though to put more substance behind the positive variant of the effect.

Since the end of World War II, there have been a total of five American presidential elections that had coattail effects: Harry Truman in 1948, Dwight Eisenhower in 1952, Lyndon Johnson in 1964, Ronald Reagan in 1980, and Barack Obama in 2008.


TBH, as with any theories implying causation from correlation, it's going to find its dissent, and is methodologically challenging, at the least.
E.g. a paper on Spain notes that "causal identification of spillovers across concurrent elections is challenging", but nonetheless claims that the direction of the effect is well established in the US:

in the United States, there is a clear hierarchy in the causal direction of the coattail from the Presidential onto the Congressional race.

OTOH a 2013 paper on the US is actually more skeptical...

Previous
estimates generally show that a one-percentage-point
increase in a presidential candidate’s vote share is associated with a 0.3- to 0.5-percentage-point increase in
the vote shares received by his party’s House candidates. Interpreting these estimates as coattails implies
that when the personal characteristics of a presidential candidate causes his vote share to increase by five
percentage points, he can lead his party’s House candidate to victory who might otherwise lose by up to
five percentage points. Using OLS, I estimate similar
associations between gubernatorial and down-ballot
statewide executive office candidates. However, my IV
point estimates indicate that a five-percentage-point increase in the personal vote received by a gubernatorial
candidate affects only the outcome of down-ballot elections in which her party would otherwise lose by fewer
than two percentage points. The difference suggests
that interpreting these previous estimates as coattails
may substantially overstate the effect of presidential
candidates on House elections.

FWTW, NYT (2021) discusses a study that found that in 2020 Biden might have benefitted from a reverse coattail effect, i.e that down-ballot races benefited him. NY Mag ponders if the same might happen in 2024.

And if you missed the breaking news,  Biden now/just dropped  out in favor of VP K. Harris. There are some Qs how definitive Biden's recommendation is though https://edition.cnn.com/2024/06/28/politics/election-biden-presidential-race-what-matters/index.html

To understand this, it helps to understand the impact of presidential elections on voter turnout. Ballotpedia has a page with stats for all US national elections since 2002. There are national elections every 2 years.  Here's a table from that page with the percentage of eligible voters that actually cast a ballot.



year
turnout




2022
46.6%


2020
66.6%


2018
50.0%


2016
60.1%


2014
36.7%


2012
58.6%


2010
41.8%


2008
62.2%


2006
41.3%


2004
60.7%


2002
40.5%



It's pretty obvious that there's a pattern here.  The presidential election years have about nearly 60% or higher voter turnout.  Other years vary roughly between 40% and 50%.
So clearly, more people show up to vote when a Presidental election is at stake.  The concern is that if democrats are not motivated by their candidate and decide to not to vote at all, that will lower their turnout which will tend to hurt other 'down-ballot' democratic candidates. This isn't specific to this election or to the democrats. It's general phenomenon for US elections: the party that wins the presidential elections tends to do well in other races held at the same time. IMO, it's an example of how direct voting for president distorts the US political system.

Technically speaking we don't vote directly for president.  We have an Electoral college.  We vote for electors, and THEY vote for President and Vice President.  Of course in modern practice this is more of an academic difference than a practical one, the only real impact of which is how it disproportionately weights votes by where they were cast.

@zibadawatimmy Good point. I shouldn't assume everyone knows that. I think does actually matter in this context, too.  In states like New York (where I live) where the state's winner is a foregone conclusion, I hypothesize that this effect is likely stronger. That is, you need more excitement/motivation around the presidential election to get people to the polls than in a 'swing state'.

Being in a similarly foregone conclusion state (and congressional district), which aligns with my own preferences, I'm definitely guilty of feeling no particular motivation to vote most of the time.  Data point of one, but I think it's a plausible sounding theory at least, and I imagine there's got to be research out there on this idea.

@zibadawatimmy If you look at the ballotpedia page I linked to, there are breakdowns by state.  I don't have time at the moment to do that kind of analysis but I think there might be evidence there. e.g. compare the turnouts in NY versus PA.

Of course there's also the fact that campaign funds are spent in those swing states to get people to the polls so untangling all that is almost surely beyond my abilities.

@JimmyJames "winner is a foregone conclusion" is an example that humans are terrible at math. They think "since my vote won't change the outcome, then I won't vote".  It is true, the odds of your vote changing the outcome in NY is astronomically low.  But it is also astronomically low in ANY state.  So by that logic, no one should bother voting... moral of the story.... people do not usually vote for logical reasons, they vote as a mob, using mob mentality.

@JohnHenckel I'm not so sure about that.  How many votes were the deciding factor in Florida in the 2000 election?

@JohnHenckel But I do think your general thrust aligns with my critique of the US system: we worry about national politics more than local politics. This seems backwards, when I think about it deeply. It should really be the other way around.

It wasn't always that way.  Abortion and Roe v. Wade was really what radically shifted American politics from a more local focus to all-in federally (though that's a bit overstated; e.g. Republican ability to remain focused on winning state and local elections has been a big issue as then they control state legislatures and policies, but much of this is done so as to warp and control the federal House). Abortion had largely been a state/local issue, but now suddenly opponents had no choice but to go national and try to control the judiciary and federal government to get their way.
